# Custom Options Menu bar issue in Android

Tags: android, menu, customization, menuitem

I am trying to create a customized Menu Bar for my app which looks like the following way

```
|===============/-----\===============|
|       |      |       |      |       | 
| item1 | item2| item3 | item4| item5 |
|=====================================|
```

the middle item is more bigger then the other items

How can I do this?

To know what I want to achieve is also shown in the following link

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

The link shows how to do that in iPhone; I am looking for the same in Android.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: http://androidworkz.com/2011/02/04/custom-menu-bar-tabs-how-to-hook-the-menu-button-to-showhide-a-custom-tab-bar/  this link might be help full

Comment: thank you for the help.. but non of these links are useful for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to catch option menu key press and show a custom view, not an option menu. In this way, you mai have any layout to your "option menu".

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will definitely try and let you know.